# Where to add pyflakes folder for static analysis in vim for python?

Tags: python, vim, pyflakes

I am having difficulty in having pyflakes in vim for statin analysis of python code. When I find folders on my system with name "ftplugin" I see following results:

/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after/ftplugin

/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after/ftplugin/ftplugin

/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftplugin

/usr/share/vim/vim72/ftplugin

Where exactly do I have to add pyflakes files? I tried all the location but that does not help. I have also set `filetype plugin indent on`. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to install plugins and colorschemes in `$HOME/.vim/`. If that directory doesn't exist already, create it.

Same deal with `$HOME/.vim/ftplugin/` and so on…

Answer (score 0):

The [installation instructions](https://github.com/kevinw/pyflakes-vim) are quite clear:

> Otherwise unzip pyflakes.vim and the pyflakes directory into `~/.vim/ftplugin/python`

so you may need to create that directory first.

But really, if you're doing anything with vim, you should use a bundle installer like Pathogen or Vundle. You won't regret it.